# What is difference between 'charge_start_threshold' and 'charge_control_start_threshold'

Tags: systemd, battery-charging-threshold

When working to configure battery charge threshold behavior, running

> ls /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0

produces two pairs of entries that seem to have the same function:

1. 'charge_start_threshold' and 'charge_control_start_threshold'
2. 'charge_stop_threshold' and 'charge_control_end_threshold'

What is the appropriate use of each of these? For example, when should 'charge_start_threshold' be used instead of 'charge_control_start_threshold'?

Answer (score 1):

`charge_start_threshold` is the legacy API (invented by `thinkpad-acpi` IIRC) and you can ignore it. You can verify that changes to one of the parameters are automatically reflected in its twin.